# App submitted successfully on iTune connect by Xcode. But it is not showing on my panel

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader, xcode-organizer

I am facing a strange problem to configure my App with iTune connect. I have uploaded my App on the iTune by Xcode organizer, it is showing successfully uploaded. But when i am login in my iTunes account and go to the application. it shows build No. and processing message, after the 20 to 30 minute the application automatically deleted from the panel.

[image]

After some time it's invisible from their.

[image]

Comment: Your app's binary gets rejected. Check your(admin account) email. Apple will give details of rejection in their email.

Comment: @pkc456 Thanks for reply.